# The width of massaction check box column in _prepareMassaction()

Tags: grid, massaction

i have a column in a custom grid

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('mymodule_name');

    $this->setMassactionIdField('tax_calculation_rate_id');
    $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('id');

    $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('check', array(
        'label'=> $helper->__('Check order exist'),
        'width'=> '5%',
        'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/massCheck', array('' => '')),        // public function massDeleteAction() in Mage_Adminhtml_Tax_RateController
        //'confirm' => $helper->__('Are you sure?')
    ));

    return $this;

}
```

the 'width'=> '5%', has none effect, anyone knows how to set the width?

Comment: What happens when you do `'width' => '70px',` instead? Does it has any effect?

Comment: no effect........

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Massaction addItem will not allow you to have width. Can you add some screenshot?

Comment: just simply adjust the width of the column without modifying the column in _prepareColumns

Comment: To adjust column width, you will need to do it from prepareColumns unfortunately.